# Why mmap-ing a file into the OS cache introduced performance bottlenecks for reads?

Tags: linux, database, mmap, rocksdb

When I was reading the [document](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/e14fbaae26be24afa2c6287f71a6574d2380413b/docs/_docs/faq.md) of RocksDB, I saw that:

> We found that mmap-ing a file into the OS cache introduced performance
>   bottlenecks for reads.

I have two questions:

1. What's the root cause of this performance?
2. How to test for this case? I am going to produce some test results of this.

Comment: With a working set of 5*physical ram size the chance of a page fault comes very near to 1.0 , since hashing (I presume it does some hashing) has no locality of reference. (in fact: the contrary; page->disk accesses are kind of random)

Comment: @joop As a KV database, the request pattern in production should have a big chance of hot data and cold data. Although random read the mmap-ing file may cause the page fault, it can be all the hot data in ram and all the cold data in the disk. In most cases, the database should be high efficient because of very few access of the cold data. Correct me if I am wrong.